# Add new nav menu item in WordPress programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add new nav menu item and in the same time create new page, so my questions are:  
Is it enough to use `wp_update_nav_menu_item()` to create new page and new item in existing nav menu?
And if that's true can I use `wp_delete_post()` to delete that new page and nav menu item that leads to that page?

Comment: For everyone that have similar problem: All you need to do to create new menu item is to use `wp_insert_post()` and `wp_update_nav_menu_item()`. And `wp_delete_post()` is enough to  delete post and remove it from menu.

Answer (score -1):

> Add new menu in nav menu bar

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 1 );
function add_loginout_link( $items) {
 if (is_user_logged_in()) {
   $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
 }
 return $items;
 }
```